# Even though we optimized the zygote preload in AOSP, why doesn't the SystemServer start earlier?

Tags: android, optimization, android-source

Here is my boot chart
[image]

[image]

I optimized preload from ZygoteInit.java

So, although the process usage has disappeared on the bootchart, the SystemServer does not start up faster. What am I missing?